# Recover DB from ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and .frm files

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, innodb, recovery

Recently My production server was corrupted due to maintenance shutdown by digital ocean. When we trying to recover our database we couldn't access our droplet. Somehow we managed to recover these (ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and some .frm) files. When i copied this files to my new mysql server(in another machine), I could't start the mysql server. I got this output

```
sudo service mysql restart
mysql stop/waiting
start: Job failed to start
```

I checked the log file and i got this error,

```
151019  8:55:27 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of $
151019  8:55:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151019  8:55:27 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151019  8:55:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151019  8:55:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
151019  8:55:27 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
151019  8:55:27 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151019  8:55:27 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151019  8:55:27 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151019  8:55:27 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151019  8:55:27 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151019  8:55:27 [ERROR] Aborting

151019  8:55:27 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151019  8:55:28 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of $
151019  8:55:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151019  8:55:28 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151019  8:55:28 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151019  8:55:28 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
151019  8:55:28 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
151019  8:55:28 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151019  8:55:28 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151019  8:55:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151019  8:55:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151019  8:55:28 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151019  8:55:28 [ERROR] Aborting

151019  8:55:28 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151019  8:55:29 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of $
151019  8:55:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151019  8:55:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151019  8:55:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151019  8:55:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
151019  8:55:29 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
151019  8:55:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151019  8:55:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
151019  8:55:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151019  8:55:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151019  8:55:29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151019  8:55:29 [ERROR] Aborting

151019  8:55:29 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I tried adding `innodb_log_file_size= 50331648` as suggested by @akuzminsky

Then I got this error log.

```
151022  6:54:13 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of $
151022  6:54:13 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151022  6:54:13 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151022  6:54:13 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151022  6:54:13 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
151022  6:54:13 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
151022  6:54:13 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151022  6:54:13 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151022  6:54:13 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 15379293
151022  6:54:13  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in file ./toucan/ormcli$
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in file ./toucan/catego$
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in file ./toucan/survey$
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in file ./toucan/compla$
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 15382291
InnoDB: Page directory corruption: infimum not pointed to
151022  6:54:13  InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):
 len 16384; hex 10cfd0d80000000000000000000000000000000000e9e915000800000000001$
InnoDB: End of page dump
151022  6:54:13  InnoDB: Page checksum 282054872, prior-to-4.0.14-form checksum$
InnoDB: stored checksum 282054872, prior-to-4.0.14-form stored checksum 3468306$
InnoDB: Page lsn 0 15329557, low 4 bytes of lsn at page end 15329557
InnoDB: Page number (if stored to page already) 0,
InnoDB: space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 0
InnoDB: Page may be a file space header page
10:54:13 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346701 K $
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x7fa4d90e2f10]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d5)[0x7fa4d8fcd175]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fa4d7d5d340]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5f058a)[0x7fa4d91e258a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x56c44e)[0x7fa4d915e44e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x576137)[0x7fa4d9168137]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5a5632)[0x7fa4d9197632]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5a6699)[0x7fa4d9198699]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x591ad3)[0x7fa4d9183ad3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x542a1a)[0x7fa4d9134a1a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x511d48)[0x7fa4d9103d48]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x41)[0x7fa4d8fcf$
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x302221)[0x7fa4d8ef4221]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x92a)[0x7fa4d8ef821a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x28ac5b)[0x7fa4d8e7cc5b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x45b)[0x7fa4d8e815db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fa4d739fec5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x286b18)[0x7fa4d8e78b18]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Please help me to resolve this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Note lines in the error log:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
The actual size of the redo log file differs from the size in MySQL config.
```

Add this line to my.cnf

```
innodb_log_file_size= 50331648
```

If the tablespace is corrupted you'll still have to heal it. But at least MySQL won't stop at this step.

Comment: I tried adding that. Now i got different error. i Updated ny question please check

Comment: No, set it to the size of the file.  If you need to change the size, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/4103#4103